# Spring mvc 3.x global .net web.config equivalent?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and I'm wondering what the equivalent of Spring's .NET globabl web.config file is and how to access custom values from that equivalent web.config file?  I want store a couple of URLs (for starters) and I need to know how to access each property globally from any controller?

Specifically for spring mvc 3.x (not sure if there is a difference or not per other versions).

What is best practice here? There seems to be a lot of variations on this theme. thx!